# Doxygen empty pages and bad margins

Tags: c++, latex, doxygen, margin

i got serious problems with doxygen generatin pdf file. First of all i got blank/empty pages I don`t know why i unchecked the option SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES (set to 0). I looked through the files and found 2 lines with /cleandoublepages or something like this i deleted this. The result was that only the first blank page dissapeard. I got also problems with marign, every even page have weird marign. I eclosed a link to package with pdf and other files which doxygen generates + config.
[File](http://www.speedyshare.com/files/30844089/latex.rar)

Answer (score 1):

You can set COMPACT_LATEX to YES to avoid empty pages. 
I'm not sure what you mean with weird margins.